# gdb returns SIGSEGV __do_global_dtors_aux ()

Tags: c, linux, gdb, segmentation-fault, cracking

I'm trying to debug a crackme file on linux using gdb but when i try run it returns

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080484fb in __do_global_dtors_aux ()
```

when i try without gdb it's running normally,
how can i debug it?

Comment: What's a "crackme file"?

Comment: Change `exit` to `_exit`?

Comment: us2012 : crackme file is executable which is created for try your reverse engineering knowledge, it's asking a password and i'm trying to crack it.
Kerrek SB : how can i do that?

Comment: Does it segfault normally or only when run inside gdb? If only the latter, that's a neat trick (if intentional).

Comment: I suspect that some destructor functions (e.g. in C++) are called "after" main

Comment: it runs normally without debugging